# Connecting 2 single switches to a stack

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, 3com

I have a core switch made with 2 stacked Cisco SG500XG-8F8T switches.

Now I have to connect 2 3Com Baseline Switch 2920-SFP Plus to extend my gigabit network, but they are not stacked. So I connected them in this way:

switch3 (3Com) port 17 (SFP) -> Cisco stack unit 2 port XG12 (SFP)
switch2 (3Com) port 17 (SFP) -> Cisco stack unit 1 port XG12 (SFP)

Units 1 and 2 of the stack are of course connected together using the stacking ports (XG15 and XG16 SFPs).

It it correct? Should I also connect switch3 between switch2 using other 2 SFPs?

On the Cisco stack I see that the port XG12 on the unit 1 is the root port for the spanning tree.

I wish to have the better fault tolerance method between switches and this is because I don't want to have 3Com switches connected to the same unit of the Cisco stack, but I'm not sure I connected them properly as I'm having some packet loss on one host which is connected on a bond interface (2 slaves) each connected to one 3Com switch (without LACP of course).

Could you help me please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How old are those 3COM switches? 7-8 years old? If so, why would you put those in your network?

Comment: They are 5 years old but they are working good. I have to use them because I don't have any left ethernet ports free in the Cisco switch and I need some additional ports for some non critical services. Why should I waste them?

Comment: I am sure that the packet loss problem is not because of the switches themselves because I have this problem only on the bonded host. Other hosts connected to the same switches but with only one NIC (for example the DRACs) does not lose any packet.